# How to fix locally Cartesian coordinates on the surface of a sphere?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, curvature, topology

Page 166 of this [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ho6KkVyZgV0C&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=local%20cartesian%20coordinate%20system%20in%20curved%20space&source=bl&ots=haXxCW32xu&sig=8SRUCNFgJhPejhwsECgVxdV76LE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihpceN9-DTAhXHQY8KHcyOBb0Q6AEISDAG#v=onepage&q=local%20cartesian%20coordinate%20system%20in%20curved%20space&f=false) says that

> any geometry, no matter how curved, is *locally flat*, at each spatial point we can always construct an infinitesimal patch of a Cartesian coordinate system.

By question is what can be (or how to think about) the local Cartesian coordinates on the surface of an unit sphere? Since it is a Cartesian coordinate the metric tensor must be $\delta_{ij}$. If I use $(x,y,z)$ system, the metric tensor does bot become $\delta_{ij}$ because of the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. In spherical polar Coordinates too, the metric is not $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Note the word "infinitesimal". The coordinates will not exactly be "on" the sphere but on the [tangent plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) to the sphere. You can think of them as generated by a choice of two perpendicular tangent vectors at the point of tangency. "Infinitesimally" tangent plane points will correspond to points of the sphere by [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)) but on any *finite* patch, no matter how small, sphere's curvature is  non-zero, so induced coordinates are not flat.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments to the post (v1):

1. By the word *locally flat* Ref. 1 seems to refer the existence of [Riemann normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), i.e. one can arrange **at a point** that (i) the metric tensor is the Kronecker delta and that (ii) the first partial derivatives of the metric vanish.
2. This result is *not* necessarily possible to extend to an **open neighborhood** because of curvature, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/156738/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161038/2451) Phys.SE posts.

References:

1. U. Leonhardt & T. Philbin, *Geometry and Light: The Science of Invisibility,* 2010; p. 166.